# Converting the GNU case range extension to standard C

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, gnu

The GNU case range extension allows case ranges in switch statements:

```
switch (value) {
    case 1 ... 8:
        printf("Hello, 1 to 8\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Hello, default\n");
        break;
}
```

How would you convert this to standard C (c99, or c89)? Add the individual case statements?

Edit: How would you handle very large switch statements specifically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
switch(value) 
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        printf("Hello, 1 to 8\n"); 
        break;     
    default:         
        printf("Hello, default\n");         
        break; 
}
```

**EDIT:** To answer the comment.
If you have too many cases, then You might want to consider replacing the **switch-case** with **if-else** constructs. It can be much cleaner, concise & readable.

```
if (value >=1 && value <= 8) 
{    
    printf("Hello, 1 to 8\n"); 
} 
else 
{   
    printf("Hello, default\n"); 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace a case 32 ... 126: :) It's going to be a long switch statement...

Comment: Is there a way to generate these cases with the C preprocessor?

Comment: @Ynv: You may want to just switch to using a series of if-else statements.

Comment: @KevinBallard: The switch statement has several hundreds SLOC :) (Character input handling in a curses application.)

Comment: @Ynv: Why did you not mention all details in the original Q? You should be posting all the relevant details when you ask a Q not selectively, reveal them as the answers pour in.Not providing all details in one-go makes the answers to your original Q's(with withheld information) irrelevant and make them look silly.

Comment: @Als: You are right, I'm sorry. I added a comment to the question. Hopes this makes the answers look appropriate.

Comment: @Ynv: Thanks. The secret to getting quick and correct answers is expressing the problem correctly and cleanly.Also,I did not mean to indicate to just accept an answer even if it doesn't satisfy you. *If* you are not happy with the existing answers You can wait for more answers to come in and then accept a answer which best helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @AlokSave add: [5.21 Case Ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges)

Answer (score 4):

I would use an `if` statement:

```
if (value >=1 && value <= 8) {
    printf("Hello, 1 to 8\n");
} else {
    printf("Hello, default\n");
}
```

You can then add extra `else if` statements if more ranges are required,

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, since the numbers are adjacent to each other, you can do a manual optimization of the switch-case.

```
typedef void(*func_t)(void);

#define CASES_N 9

void func0 (void)
{
  printf("Hello, 0\n");
}

void func1 (void)
{
  printf("Hello, 1 to 8\n");
}

static const func_t execute [CASES_N] =
{
  &func0,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1,
  &func1
};

int main()
{
  if(what < CASES_N)
  {
    execute[what]();
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Hello, default\n");
  }
}
```

This code is basically the same as a compiler-optimized switch-statement.

Answer (score 2):

If long long range you could do, a bit dirty but,

```
switch(what) {
case 1:
    /* do 1 */
    break;
case 2:
    /* do 2 */
    break;
default:
    if (what > 31 && what < 127) {
         /* do 32 to 126 */
    }
}
```

The best would <strike>probably</strike> be to remove the switch for an if all together.

Be extremely strict with nesting. If you want the switch, for some reason, then better then the above would be:

```
if (value > 31 && value < 127) {
  /* Do something */
} else {
    switch (value) {
    case 1:
        ...
    }
}
```

Ach, sorry for edit again. **This** would be cleaner.

```
if (value > 31 && value < 127) {
  /* Do something */
} else if (value > 127 && value < 178) {

} else if ( ...

}

switch (value) {
case 1:
    ...
}
```