# How can I use ranges in a switch case statement in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

My logic is:

```
if number is between 1 to 10, execute first case statement
if number is from 20 to 30, execute second case statement
```

is there a solution other than the one below?

```
case '1' ... '10':
case '20' ... '30':
```

Comment: Your only options are to do as you don't want to or as pzaenger suggests.

Comment: If you want a non portable solution, gcc can use range based case.

Comment: You mean `1 ... 10`, not `'1' ... '10'`. And that construct is a gcc extension, not standard C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting the GNU case range extension to standard C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922837/converting-the-gnu-case-range-extension-to-standard-c)

Answer (score 36):

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler supports, as a *language extension*, [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) like:

```
 switch(i) {
    case 0 ... 9: return true;
    default: return false;
 }
```

This language extension is also accepted by [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). So use it if you can afford restricting your code to GCC & Clang compilers.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924681/are-elipses-in-case-statements-standard-c-c).

I have no idea why this extension was not included in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard.

Notice also that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) accepts [computed or indirect `goto` and labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). There are cases (in particular in
*generated* C code) where these features are useful. Examples could include some efficient [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreter. Some implementations of the Ocaml [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) are a good example.

Answer (score 6):

```
void SwitchDemo(int value)
   {
   switch(value / 10)
      {
      case 0: ...; break; // 0 - 9
      case 1: ...; break; // 10 - 19
      ...
      }
   }
```

or, specific to the question ranges:

```
void SwitchDemo(int value)
   {
   switch((value-1) / 10)
      {
      case 0: ...; break; // 1 - 10
      case 1: ...; break; // 11 - 20
      ...
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: use `case 0` for `0-9`, `case 1` for `11-20` and so on.

Option 2: use `if`

Option 3:

Another shabby way is using fall through cases like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=1;

    for(i=1;i<=25;i++)
    {
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
            printf("%d  is in between 1-10\n", i);
            break;

        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
        case 16:
        case 17:
        case 18:
        case 19:
        case 20:
            printf("%d  is in between 11-20\n", i);
            break;

        default:
            printf("%d  is above 20\n", i);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1  is in between 1-10
2  is in between 1-10
3  is in between 1-10
4  is in between 1-10
5  is in between 1-10
6  is in between 1-10
7  is in between 1-10
8  is in between 1-10
9  is in between 1-10
10  is in between 1-10
11  is in between 11-20
12  is in between 11-20
13  is in between 11-20
14  is in between 11-20
15  is in between 11-20
16  is in between 11-20
17  is in between 11-20
18  is in between 11-20
19  is in between 11-20
20  is in between 11-20
21  is above 20
22  is above 20
23  is above 20
24  is above 20
25  is above 20
```

https://ideone.com/Cw6HDO

Comment: In which case `switch` might not be the way to go.

Comment: If you have to check thousands of numbers, you should have mentioned that in your original question.

Comment: you mean you have 1000s of ranges to check for? if yes then use `if`, if numbers are in 1000s but ranges are few then you can use `switch`

Comment: @user3205621 consider writing a short program to generate the source code for you, then copy/paste, or include the file ;)

Comment: Note: `switch()` statements might not support more than 1023 `case` labels:  C11 §5.2.4.1 1

Comment: likely he had 1024 numbers, and could have ranged them to a scale of 1..10. Just saying, a lot of Arduino programmers want to do this.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't support case values other than single integers (or integer-like things -- characters, enumeration values). So your options are:

- As suggested by pzaenger in a now-deleted comment: transform the number you're working with into something you *can* switch on (in this case, divide by 10).
- Multiple case statements (taking advantage of fallthrough): `case 1: case 2: case 3: ... case 10: do_something();`
- Use `if` rather than `case`.

Answer (score 1):

In the C programming language the `case` statement used in a `switch()` statement must specify a value that the compiler can turn into a constant in some way. Each of the values used in the `case` statements must be unique within the scope of the `switch()`. The `default` keyword indicates the default if none of the `case` statements match the expression in the `switch()` statement.

As an aside, check out Duff's Device to show an interesting use of `switch()` and `case`. See [How does Duff's device work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)

So the following shows several examples of proper `case` statements in a `switch()`:

```
#define XXVAL 2
#define CASETEST(x) (x + 5)

int iValue;
//  set the value of the variable iValue at some point
switch (iValue) {
case 0:
    // do the case if iValue == 0
    break;
case XXVAL:
    // do the case if iValue == XXVAL
    break;
case CASETEST(3):
    // do the case if iValue == CASETEST(3)
    // works because preprocessor generates the source text which is
    // then compiled and the expression can be resolved to a constant
    break;
case CASETEST(5) * 2:
    // do the case if iValue == CASETEST(5) * 2
    // works because preprocessor generates the source text which is
    // then compiled and the expression can be resolved to a constant
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

What you can do if you still want to use  a `switch()` with ranged `case` statements is to provide some mechanism to fold the expression into one or more specific constant values.

So in a simple, trivial example you could do something like the following. This is a trivial case to show the technique which ends up making the logic of the simple `if` statements opaque. This technique can be useful for complex decisions and classification that can be folded into a simple set of constants.

```
int foldit (int iValue)
{
    if (iValue < 5000) return 0;
    else if (iValue < 10000) return 1;
    else if (ivalue < 20000) return 2;
    else return 9999;   // triggers the default part of the switch
}

switch (foldit(iValue)) {
case 0:
    // do what is needed for up to but not including 5000
    break;
case 1:
    // do what is needed for 5000 up to but not including 10000
    break;
case 2:
    // do what is needed for 10000 up to but not including 20000
    break;
default:
    // handle anything else
    break;
}
```

Where the fold approach can be helpful is when you have several different results perhaps using a filter to try to classify a data item.

```
#define type1  0x00001
#define type2  0x00002
#define type3  0x00004
#define type4  0x00008

struct datatype {
    int iVal;
    int jVal; 
};

unsigned long is_a_type1(struct datatype * thing)
{
    unsigned long retVal = 0;   // initialize to not a type1, set to type1 if turns out to be
    // do checks for the type and if so set retVal to type1 if it matches
    return retVal;
}

unsigned long is_a_type2(struct datatype * thing)
{
    unsigned long retVal = 0;   // initialize to not a type2, set to type2 if turns out to be
    // do checks for the type and if so set retVal to type2 if it matches
    return retVal;
}

unsigned long is_a_type3(struct datatype * thing)
{
    unsigned long retVal = 0;   // initialize to not a type3, set to type3 if turns out to be
    // do checks for the type and if so set retVal to type3 if it matches
    return retVal;
}

unsigned long is_a_type4(struct datatype * thing)
{
    unsigned long retVal = 0;   // initialize to not a type4, set to type4 if turns out to be
    // do checks for the type and if so set retVal to type4 if it matches
    return retVal;
}

unsigned long classify (struct datatype *thing)
{
    unsigned long ulTestResult = 0;

    // test to see if this is a type1 thing
    ulTestResult |= is_a_type1(thing);

    // test to see if this is a type2 thing
    ulTestResult |= is_a_type2(thing);

    // test to see if this is a type3 thing
    ulTestResult |= is_a_type3(thing);

    // test to see if this is a type4 thing
    ulTestResult |= is_a_type4(thing);

    return ulTestResult;
}

int main ()
{
    struct datatype myThing;
    //  other source code then
    switch (classify(&myThing)) {
    case type1 | type2 | type3:
        // do stuff if this is a type1, type2, and type3 but not type4
        // that is classify() determined that myThing matched all three types.
        break;
    case type1:
        // do stuff if type1 which includes stuff you do for type2 as well under
        // special values of myThing.
        if (myThing.iVal < 50) {
            case type2:
                // at this point we have type2 case stuff that we do. Code above is skipped
                // and the switch () will jump straight to here if classify() is type2.
                //
                // Also stuff we do if type1 and myThing.iVal < 50
                // in other words this code is execute if classify(&myThing) is type2 or
                // if classify(&myThink) is type1 and there is a special processing for myThing.iVal < 50
                break;  // if classify() type2 or if classify() type1 and myThing.ival < 50
            }
        // do stuff if only type1 and myThing.iVal >= 50
        break;
    case type2 | type3:
        // do stuff if type2 and type3 matched but none of the others.
        break;
    default:
        // any other case
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements in c can only operate on a constant expression, the case statements cannot include dynamic comparisons.

[Example of something which is, and is not, a "Constant Expression" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755524/example-of-something-which-is-and-is-not-a-constant-expression-in-c)

For something this simple an if/else structure could be clearer and simpler, depending on the compiler your case statement may be translated into a series of branching comparison statements anyways.

Comment: The `switch()` **can** operate a non-constant expression in the _expression_ portion of `switch ( expression ) ...`