# Why the case label doesn't reduce to an integer constant in this particular program?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
int main() {
    int marks;
    printf("enter the marks :");
    scanf(" %d", &marks);

    switch (marks) {
      case (marks >= 90):
        printf("Excellent");
        break;
      case (marks < 90 && marks >= 75):
        printf("very good");
        break;
      case (marks < 40):
        printf("poor");
        break;
      default:
        printf("no marks available");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I recently started learning C and while running the `switch` statement I just ran into this case label error.

Please someone fix this?

Comment: Because C's `switch/case` is not a `match`? You cannot use it like this, `case`s are simply integer constant expressions.

Comment: You can't put ranges in a `switch...case`, only individual values. You would have to chain `if...else if...else` statements.

Comment: Why do you trhink it is a _constant expression_?

Comment: Why would you use `case` where `if..else if..else` is the natural way to go?

Comment: You don't put a test under `case`. The `switch-case` statement is made for value select, not greater than, smaller than. Use `if-else` for that...

Comment: The value after case should be `int` or `char` strictly

Comment: Note that the GCC compiler accepts ranges, but this is compiler specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748934/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use ranges in a switch case statement in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748934/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-in-c)

Comment: @akshayk07 it is actually an `int` here but what he needs is a "constant expression".

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya in C, `int` and `char` are essentially the same?

Comment: @akshayk07 And that is related why?

Comment: @akshayk07 In C, `int` and `char` are different types.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You said it's just an `int` , but if they are the same...

Comment: @akshayk07 I am saying what he has here is an `int`, but it's not a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

The case must be constant.  `case (marks>=90):` does not employ a constant.

> The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of the `case` constant expressions in the `same` switch statement shall have the same value after conversion" §6.8.4.2 3

Example:

```
switch (grade) {
  case 'A': printf("Excellent"); break;
  case 'B': printf("very good"); break;
  case 'C': // fall though (no break)
  case 'D': printf("poor"); break;
  default: printf("Hmmm");
}
```

---

OP's code would be better served with `if(), else if(), else`

```
// switch(marks){
// case (marks>=90):
if (marks>=90) {
    printf("Excellent");
} else if (marks>=75) {
    printf("very good");
} else if (marks < 40){  // Perhaps OP wants (marks > 40) here
    printf("poor");
} else {
    printf("no marks available");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To "fix" this, you would have to write

```
switch( marks )  // branch to the label corresponding to the value stored in marks
{
  case 100:
  case  99:
  // repeat with cases 98 through 91.  
  case  90: 
    printf( "Excellent!\n" );
    break;

  case 89:
  case 88:
  // repeat with cases 87 through 76
  case 75:
    printf( "very good\n" );
    break;

  // pattern should be obvious from here
}
```

`case` labels *must* be integer constant expressions, basically something that can be evaluated at compile time.  Relational expressions like `marks >= 90` don't count as constant expressions.

A `switch` branches to the label corresponding to the *value* of `marks`; IOW, if you want to execute an action when the value of `marks` is anywhere from `90` to `100`, then you a separate label for each value as above.

You would normally not use a `switch` statement where ranges of values are involved like this; this is better done with an `if-else` statement.

**Edit**

For reference, the following may be used as `case` labels:

- An integer literal (decimal, hex, or octal format);
- A character constant (such as `'A'`, `'?'`, `'\n'`, etc.);
- An enumeration constant;
- An arithmetic expression composed of any of the previous expressions;
- A macro that expands to any of the previous expressions;

A `const`-qualified variable is not a *constant expression* as far as C is concerned, so you can't do something like this:

```
const int foo = 10;
...
switch( bar )
{
  case foo: ... // compiler will yell at you here
```

You can't branch on strings in a `switch`; however, you can compute an integer hash for a string, and branch based on that:

```
#define FOO_HASH 0xb887389 // result of running hash function on "foo"
#define BAR_HASH 0xb8860ba // result of running hash function on "bar"

/**
 * djb2 is a popular hash function
 * see http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html for others
 */
unsigned long hash( const char *text )
{
  const unsigned char *str = (const unsigned char *) text;
  unsigned long hash = 5381;
  int c;

  while (c = *str++)
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

  return hash;
}

char text[SIZE];
if ( !fgets( text, sizeof text, stdin ) )
  // bail on input error

// remove newline from text somehow

switch( hash( text ) )
{
  case FOO_HASH: 
    // do something
    break;

  case BAR_HASH: 
    // do something else
    break;
}
```

Comment: Good explanation.  In researching this it seems code like `case INT_MAX/2: ...` is OK too.  As I see it. `case UINTMAX_MAX: ...` is OK too, although using wider that `int` is not something I have done in production code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't put a condition under a case. from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm:

*The constant-expression for a case must be the same data type as the variable in the switch, and it must be a constant or a literal.*

Comment: I think the value after case should be `int` or `char` strictly.

Comment: @akshayk07 Needs to be a _conditional-expression_.  `char` is not special here.

Comment: "The constant-expression for a case must be the same data type ..." is not for C.  Perhaps Java.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya _constant-expression_ is defined as a _conditional-expression_.

Comment: @chux I did not know that! Thanks.