# Syntax for case range in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I want to make a switch statement for in my code whose cases go over a wide span of integers (1-15000) split into 3 sections: 1-5000,5001-10000,10001-15000.

I tried it once like this:

```
switch(number) {
    case 1 ... 1000: (statement here);
```

This gave me a syntax error on the "..."- "expected a :".

Then I tried:

```
switch (number) {
case 1:
case 5000:
    (statement);
    break;
```

This method did compile but didn't work as intended, wrong answer for the cases which were not explicitly listed.

Couldn't find any other suggestions online.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot do it in (standard) C. You have to use `if`

Comment: Roger that. I'll try, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748934/how-can-i-use-ranges-in-a-switch-case-statement-in-c

Comment: This question does actually have a difference to the other questions 'already answered'.  In this case the ranges are equally sized.  try taking advantage of the inherent floor division like this `switch( (number-1)/5000 ) {
case 0: 
    break;
case 1: 
    break;
case 2:
    break;
default:
 }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible in standard C, although some compilers offer switching on a range as a compiler extension<sup>1</sup>.

The idiomatic way in your case is to write

```
if (number < 1){
    // oops
} else if (number <= 5000){
    // ToDo
} else if (number <= 10000){
    // ToDo
} else if (number <= 15000){
    // ToDo
} else {
    // oops
}
```

Or a very crude way would be to write `switch((number - 1) / 5000)` which exploits integer division: mapping the cases you need to deal with to 0, 1, and 2.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

Comment: Yes I ended up doing just that, thanks.

Comment: @Hitopopamus: The `if` block I hope, not the `switch` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @UnholySheep said in the comments, you cannot do this. Not with standard C. Try using if:

```
if (my_variable >= minumum_value && my_variable <= maximum_value) {
// Do something
} else {
// Do something else
}
```